# Load image using $resource in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, flask, angular-resource

I have a basic web app, with a Python/Flask backend exposing an image through the API as shown:

```
class ImageResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return send_file('path/to/file', mimetype='image/jpeg')
...
api.add_resource(ImageResource, '/v1/preview')
```

In AngularJS, I then have a factory which creates the API, providing access this as a $resource:

```
var previewResource = $resource('/v1/preview')
```

This would be easy enough if I could use the following HTML

```
<img ng-src="{{ imgUrl }}" />
```

with `$scope.imgUrl` set to `'/v1/preview'`.

The problem is that the controller where I want to actually get the image can only reference `previewResource` - with no knowledge of the path.

How can I use this to retrieve the image and have it displayed on the page?

--

For some additional context (in case it makes a difference), the image will be constantly changing so there will be some `$timeout` action to refresh it every few seconds. Again, here it would be easy if the path is known, as it would be possible to have a bit of JS to append `?(timestamp)` to have the browser automatically reload it every time it changes.